# How do I reference a jQuery selector using TypeScript and DefinitelyTyped?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, definitelytyped

I'm creating a method in [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) that should receive a jQuery selector as a parameter and I want to make it strongly typed by using [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped). How should my method be like?

Example:

```
class Foo {
    constructor($el: jQuerySelector) {
    }
}
```

What should I replace `jQuerySelector` with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

e.g. `$('div')` in the DefinitelyTyped jquery.d.ts is named `JQuery`.

Comment: Thanks, my `jQuerySelector` should be just `jQuery`.

Comment: @AndréPena Note the capital `J` in `JQuery` instead of `jQuery`. This holds for all the other types defined in that file such as `JQueryXHR` and `JQueryPromise`.